# Proof that the Galois Field of order 8 is a field.

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

We know that the Galois Field of order 8 is isomorphic with $$\left( Z_2[x]^{< 3}, +_{d(x)}, \times_{d(x)}\right) $$ (Field of polynomials with coefficients in $Z_2$ and of grade smaller than 3, and $+_{d(x)}$ and $\times_{d(x)}$ being the sum and multiplication $mod(d(x))$ )

Is it thus sufficient to prove that $\left( Z_2[x]^{< 3}, +_{d(x)}, \times_{d(x)}\right) $ is a field? Is there a better way?

Subquestion: Which polynomial d(x) should I consider? Since there are two possible here: $x^3+x^2+1$ and $x^3+x+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is a little confusing but I guess I can answer part of your question at least.

Every finite field of same order is isomorphic to each other so it is indeed sufficient to construct a field of order 8 to know exactly how the field operates.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}:=\mathbb{F}_2$ is a field it is sufficient to obtain an irreducible polynomial of degree 3 to construct a field of order 8. Either of the polynomial you mentioned are irreducible so

$$\mathbb{F}_2[x]/d(x)$$ where $d(x)$ can be chosen to be any of the two polynomial you mentioned, is a field of order 8. They will be isomorphic but the isomorphism won't necessarily be easy to construct.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If I may ask, what could be another example of field of order 8? (I really struggle visualising this stuff)

Comment: (Which is probably why it's called abstract algebra :-) )

Comment: Every finite field of order $8$ is isomorphic so I am not sure what else I could give you. in http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=finite+field+of+order+8 there is table which illustrates multiplication and addition but you are not supposed to 'visualise' this kind of stuff anyways.

I found out the term Galois field is the term engineers use for finite field. Are you based in engineering?

Comment: I'm an engineering student indeed. Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: For the polynomials $X^3+X+1$ and $X^3+X^2+1$, the roots of one are the reciprocals of the roots of the other.